# No view found for id 0x7f080035 (com.androidjetpackph:id/container) for fragment PostFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

I want to create a contract for all the activites to have, for that reason I am creating a base activity, but for some reason the error regarding the R.id.container shows up.

I am doing a Base Activity with the following code:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    @LayoutRes
    abstract fun layoutToInflate(): Int

    abstract fun doOnCreated()

    open fun initialFragment(): Fragment? = null

    abstract fun defineInitialFragment()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        doOnCreated()
    }

}
```

This is my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun layoutToInflate() = R.layout.activity_main

    override fun doOnCreated() {
        defineInitialFragment()
    }

    override fun initialFragment() = PostFragment.newInstance()

    override fun defineInitialFragment() {
        val initialFragment = initialFragment() ?: return
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, initialFragment)
                .commitNow()
    }
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity" />
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your posted code, this is your base `onCreate()`:

> ```
> override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>     doOnCreated()
> }
> ```

And this is your subclass:

> ```
> override fun doOnCreated() {
>     defineInitialFragment()
> }
> ```

In neither of these places do you actually set the activity's content view. You have to call `setContentView(layoutToInflate())` somewhere, probably in your base activity's `onCreate()`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(layoutToInflate())
    doOnCreated()
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thats it!!

Comment: One more question not related, is dagger really worth using,our should I make my own Injection, and as a back-end language for mobile consumption do you recommend nodejs? Thanks and sorry for the two questions